# AngularJS bootstrapUI : How to render a dynamic page inside the modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the modal function to display a full sized image.

```
            $scope.openModalPicture = function (id) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: '../user/picture/'+id,
                    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
                });
            };
```

So if I call in my browser http://whatever.com/user/picture/10 it will render some html with the picture. The problem is that angular loads the http://whatever.com/user/picture/10 at page load. If the picture of user 10 change after the page load and I click to call `openModalPicture` function, I still get the previous image.

I figured out that the `templateUrl` is just a local template and everything goes with $scope variables.
The only solution seems to retrieve the data I need through `$http` request and fill the local templateUrl, or is there another trick?

Edit : See the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkhaSfE7yafiRciOKLt8?p=preview

Comment: please show your html and setup a demo. What you want to achieve is straightforward. If you setup a plunkr or jsfiddle, I will show you how to do it

Comment: Just explain the way to do it, I don't need code.

Comment: Just read the doc. You customize the template

Comment: @apairet I made a plunker for you

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to your modal. so if you have the right URL for your picture in your main controller, just pass it the modal when you open it.

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        size:'sm',
        resolve: {
            picture: function() {
                //you can pass any other parameter instead of hard-coded string of course
                return "http://freedogpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pictures_1407299643.jpg";
            }
        }
    });
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, picture) {
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.picture = picture;
};
```

and the template:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><span ng-click="cancel()">Close</span></td>
    <td><img ng-src="{{picture}}" border="0"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've modified your plunkr with [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ih7stD8TjvtqlvSHsLjt?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem here is that if I decide to add some features like comments in the dynamic page, with your solution I will have to pass them into the modal too, right? I think the best solution will be to use an iframe in the modal template with the dynamic page as source no ?

Comment: @yarons answer is good. I do not see the point of using an iframe.